# How can I use the boolean value in the "jump" method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a jumping system to my rpg. --> problems with detecting when player is grounded.

I have tried to make the system return boolean value and add it with if method to the jump method, unfortunately im stuck

```
bool isGrounded () 
{
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround);
}

//jump Force
if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
{
    if(isGrounded == true) 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector3.up * 100);
    }
}
```

Error message here.

> bool isGrounded()
>   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'bool' (CS0019) [Assembly-CSharp]

Comment: You can shorten the check to `if(isGrounded)` The conditions are evaluated to a boolean and if you name those properly, you need no extra check. In your case there seems to be a name ambiguity, however. There is apparenly a variable of type "Method group" with the name "isGrounded", as well as the boolean. So the compiler is really confused why you would try to compare a Method group to `== true`

Comment: Simply add `()` after `isGrounded` since you defined it as method. Or convert it to a property like `bool isGrounded { get { return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround); } }` instead. Btw avoid to have multiple calls of `GetComponent` rather store it once and re-use the reference

Comment: `if(isGrounded() == true)`. You're missing parenthesis on `isGrounded()`.

Comment: Error messages of the form `cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and...` generally involve the code missing the parens required for a method call. See marked duplicates, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Adding this as an answer so this doesn't sit on the unanswered question list until the end of time*

```
bool isGrounded () 
{
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround);
}

//jump Force
if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
{
    if(isGrounded == true) 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (Vector3.up * 100);
    }
}
```

The line

```
if(isGrounded == true)
```

Tells the compiler to find a symbol named `isGrounded` and compare its value to `true`. Since `isGrounded` is a method, and not a boolean property or field, you're basically asking the compiler to compare the address of `isGrounded()` to `true`, which makes exactly zero sense (even if it was allowed in C#, which it is not).

If you change this to,

```
if(isGrounded() == true)
```

or, more succinctly,

```
if(isGrounded())
```

It'll call `isGrounded()` and test the return value.

Parenthesis are important.